# accessing conditional indices in tensor in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Suppose I have a tensor `X` with rank 2 with the first rank corresponding to the batch size of, say, some samples `x` with dimension K. It is easy to access k-th element of all samples: `X[1:batch_size,k]`. But suppose I need to access k_i-th element of x_i for all i. For example, if I have `k_list = [1, 2, ..., 2]`, the only way I know of to access k_i-th element of x_i for all i is

```
out=[X[i,k_list[i]] for all i in range(len(k_list))]
```

The problem is this makes my code really slower. Can we anyway optimize this code?

Note*: I actually have `k_list` as a placeholder. The size of `np.shape(X)=(batch_size,K)`, `np.shape(k_list)=(batch_size,)`, `np.maximum(k_list)=K-1, np.minimum(k_list)=0`, and `np.shape(out)=(batch_size,1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking for `gather_nd`

```
i0 = tf.range(batch_size, dtype=tf.int32)
indices = tf.stack((i0, k_list), axis=1)
out = tf.gather_nd(X, indices)
```

Comment: If that doesn't help, please post the dimensions of `X` and `k_list`, along with your expected output shape.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Will do.

Comment: I just clarified the dimensions. But I need to try first your solution. Thanks.